# How to make Fiddler show POST method only in many requests

Tags: fiddler

Usually, We capture too many requests via *Fiddler*, But the requests with POST method is finally what we want.

Is there any way to extract/filter/ the these requests with **POST** method, in other words, show the **POST** requests only.

I've read the filter part on Fiddler Docs, But nothing clue to this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of ways to do this in Fiddler, the simplest is probably using the QuickExec box:

1. In the QuickExec box write `=POST`

[image: =POST]

2. Then, clicking `Enter` will highlight only the requests with `POST` method

[image: Filter applied]